# Global Stability Difference Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the first-order non-linear difference equation:
\begin{equation}
k_{t+1} = sf(k_t) + (1-\delta)k_t
\end{equation}
where $s$ and $\delta$ are two constants and $s,\delta \in (0,1)$.
I assume that $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+$ is twice continuously differentiable and $f'(k)>0$ and $f''(k)<0$ for all $k>0$. So, $f(k)$ is assumed to be strictly concave.

At the steady state, $k^{\ast}$ (fixed point) satsifies the following equation:
\begin{equation}
s f(k^{\ast}) = \delta k^{\ast}
\end{equation}

Now, pls, tell me if it's correct how I prove global stability:

First,
\begin{equation}
k_{t+1} = g(k_t)
\end{equation}
and for $k^{\ast}$ being a fixed point it must be
\begin{equation}
k^{\ast} = g(k^{\ast})
\end{equation}

Then, for all $k_t \in (0,k^{\ast})$,
\begin{equation}
k_{t+1} - k^{\ast} = g(k_t) - g(k^{\ast}) = - \int_{k_t}^{k^{\ast}} g'(k) dk <0
\end{equation}
The inequality holds because $g'(k)>0$ for all $k$.

This result shall ensure that for any $k_t \in (0,k^{\ast})$, then $k_{t+1}$ is always lower than $k^{\ast}$, and the convergence of $k \to k^{\ast}$ is ensured from the fact that
\begin{equation}
\gamma(k_t) = \frac{k_{t+1} -k_t}{k_t} = \frac{s f(k_t) + (1-\delta)k_t - k_t}{k_t} = \frac{sf(k_t)}{k_t} - \delta
\end{equation}
and since $h(k_t) \equiv k_t/f(k_t)$ is strictly increasing in $k$ and $h(k^{\ast})=s/\delta$, then the growth rate of $k$ is positive but strictly decreasing in $k$, with $\gamma(k)>0$ iff $k< k^{\ast}$ and $\gamma(k)=0$ iff $k= k^{\ast}$.

A similar argument applies to $k_t > k^{\ast}$. Is that correct?